# Allowing UIScrollView to scroll with 2nd touch while a long press is active

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a long press recognizer attached to a UIScrollView (actually a UITableView). When the long press is active, I cannot scroll with a second finger.

What do I need for the UIScrollView's pan recognizer to consume the second touch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `YES` from `-gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`. To do this, at least one of the gesture recognizer’s `delegate` properties needs to be set set `self`.

Comment: Heh, I found this solution just a minute before you answered. Works great.